Why is my static analyzer taking so long?
Why is my static analyzer taking so long to run?
I am currently doing a unity project in rider ide and am facing this issue when i try implement the net analyzer by microsoft onto the gitlab ci pipeline. On the ide when i run it completes within seconds however when i pushed it onto gitlab it takes more than 10 minutes to complete. On gitlab i can see that the echo appears but it just hangs until 10 - 15 minutes mark before it ends. Anyone knows why or how to fix this?
build_static_analyzer:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - msdk-unity
  interruptible: true
  before_script:
    - cd $PROJECT_DIR
    - /Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity -quit -batchmode -projectPath . -executeMethod UnityEditor.SyncVS.SyncSolution
  script:
    - echo "Starting static analysis..."
    - dotnet msbuild msdk-unity2020.sln /p:RunAnalyzers=true /p:RunAnalyzersDuringBuild=true /p:Configuration=Debug /p:WarningLevel=4 /p:AnalysisMode=All /p:NoBuild=true
    - echo "Static analysis completed."
    - sleep 5 
      


Can you share one pipeline as an example?
